# php Header function not working , also not giving any error

Tags: php, function, redirect, header

I have the following code for a page where i am using a header function :

```
        <?php
        if (!defined('pagescope')) die('Please Try your Luck Somewhere else! Your IP Address has been logged!');
        define('pagescope', 'true');
        require'config.php';

                            *some Query processing with no echo command                                      

                            //$query1 = "select * from users";
                            if($query_run = mysql_query($query))
                            {                                                                    

                                $id=mysql_insert_id();

                                header("Location:     http://www.pingcampus.com/mysql/cropupload/jquery_upload_cropv1.2/upload_dp.php?id=$id&email=$contact_email&gender=$gender");
                                } else {
                                    echo mysql_error();

                                }                                               

                               ?>
```

**I Have made sure that there are no echo statements on the page, also there are no errors given! But it just doesn't redirects! Also it works fine on my Localhost but not on my hosting **

Comment: get rid of `?>` if it's at the last line, do the same for `config.php` and see if the problem's gone

Comment: Perhaps you should turn on error reporting, then (for development)? Or check the error logs?

Comment: @Robbie i haven't mentioned error_reporting(0); anywhere in the code that itself means that it should give me errors if there are any right?

Comment: @AnilJain not necessarrily chances might be ou have error eporting turned of in your PHP.ini, try placing the code `error_reporting(E_ALL)` on top of your page and see if you get any error

Comment: Quite the opposite. On a production server the error_reporting level is usually low (you want to increase it for debugging) and display_errors is et to "off". You can turn display errors to "on" for debugging, then turn off when exposed to the world. Or, as I said, check the logs.

Comment: @SiGanteng I did that, still no help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
if($result) {
    $id = mysql_insert_id();
    header("Location:http://www.pingcampus.com/mysql/cropupload/jquery_upload_cropv1.2/upload_dp.php?id=$id&email=$contact_email&gender=$gender");
}
```

UPDATE :

your error states that header is already being sent, do a proper check in other part of script. or what you can do is use output buffering.

place `ob_start();` on top of your script.

> this will turn output buffering on. While output buffering is active
>   no output is sent from the script (other than headers), instead the
>   output is stored in an internal buffer.

more information here. http://php.net/ob_start

Comment: can you tell me what exact lines of code should i replace for this one?

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bosweb/web054/b548/ipg.pingcampuscom/mysql/register.php:6) in /hermes/bosweb/web054/b548/ipg.pingcampuscom/mysql/form.php on line 74



this is the error i am getting after error_reporting(E_ALL);
I understand this is due to some output somewhere in the files, but i think i have to put some outputs there, is there any way around?? Any other function rather than header();

Comment: that means the header is already being sent in some part of script, if you want to get it to work then place `ob_start();` at top of your code. just after `error_reporting()`

Comment: umm , okay thanks for the help but, I have a page called register.php which includes 12388.php which includes user_register.php which again includes form.php

Ignore why have i done that 

What i want to ask is on which page should i place ob_start();

Comment: if any of the page have any HTML element being printed or echo function used then that may be the cause of problem.

Comment: M sorry i was occupied ! I am gonna do it right away! Sorry for the delay

Answer (score 0):

Use ob_start() for output buffering. Check the manual Link- [Manual Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)